# DocuSign embedded document, with prefilled name and 3 spots to sign

Tags: docusignapi

I have a Django website, and each account needs a DocuSign section where everyone gets the same document loaded/embedded but has their own name prefilled on the application and has the same 3 spots for signing. What API tools from DocuSign should I look into in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by downloading the [python code example](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-python). There are 31 API scenarios examples.  You can reference API calls documentation in [here](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference). As it looks like you are going to use embedded signing a great place to read about this is [here](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/embedding)